# Check for condition and insert column in EXCEL worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I  have a table in excel. I want to check the name of the column and if is true i want to insert a new column otherwise it must continue checking.

i can't find anything to do it

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problem did you run into? Your subject says Row but your question says Column.

Comment: Till now i did it manually (find the column that i need) and then i insert the column. Then i continue to check to find the next column and keep checking)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Παράδειγμα εισαγωγής στήλης - excmple of column insertion]

```
Sub test()
   Call addNewCol(Me, "PINAKAS1", "Στήλη3")
End Sub

Private Sub addNewCol(ws As Worksheet, tableName As String, colName As String)
   Dim lst As ListObject, h As Long
   Set lst = ws.ListObjects(tableName)
   If lst Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox ("addNewCol> " & tableName & " don't exist")
   End If
   With lst
      For h = 1 To .ListColumns.Count
      If .ListColumns(h).Name = colName Then
         .ListColumns.Add Position:=h
         Exit Sub
      End If
      Next
   End With
End Sub
```